# Delete and shift values in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do you delete and `shift` up specific values in `pandas df`. For the `df` below I want to delete the `string` `'Remove'` and the 2 adjacent values and then `shift` the next `row` up.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'A' : ['X','Y','X','X','Y'],           
    'B' : ['Remove','A','X','Remove','A'],
    'C' : ['stri','Big','Y','st','Big'],
    'D' : ['ng','Cat','X','ring','Cat'],          
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Out:

```
   A       B    C    D
0  X  Remove  stri  ng
1  Y       A  Big  Cat
2  X       X    Y    X
3  X  Remove  st  ring
4  Y       A  Big  Cat
```

I have used `df['B'] = df['B'].shift(-1)` but this only removes the first value.

My intended output is:

```
   A  B    C    D
0  X  A  Big  Cat
1  Y             
2  X  X    Y    X
3  X  A  Big  Cat
4  Y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
cols  = ['B','C','D']
m = (df['B'] == 'Remove')
#set empty string to rows with Remove
df.loc[m, cols] = ''

#chain 2 boolean mask for possible shift up
mask = m | m.shift()
df.loc[mask, cols]  = df.loc[mask, cols].shift(-1)

#last replace NaNs by empty strings
df = df.fillna('')
print (df)
   A  B    C    D
0  X  A  Big  Cat
1  Y             
2  X  X    Y    X
3  X  A  Big  Cat
4  Y
```